# fire ng-change in select option in ng-repeat table row angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I want to fire `ng-change` in select option in `ng-repeat` table row to set the Unit Price against the Item Selected, but `ng-change` event is not firing in edit mode here is my code:

```
<table id="tblDetails" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr#.</th>
            <th class="col-md-5">Item</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Qty.</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Disc. Rate</th>
            <th>Discount </th>
            <th>Net Amount</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>

                <select id="s2_2" class="s2_2" ng-model="ItemCode" ng-change="getUnitPrice(ItemCode)" data-placeholder="Pick a number">

                    <option ng-repeat="c in itemList | filter:filterItem" ng-selected="{{c.Selected}}" value="{{c.Item_Code}}">{{c.Item_Name}}</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control smallInput" ng-model="UnitPrice" id="ItemPrice">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control smallInput smallInput-sm1" ng-model="Quantity" />
            </td>
            <td>
                {{PurchaseCost =(Quantity) * (UnitPrice)}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control smallInput smallInput-sm1 " ng-model="DiscountRate" />

            </td>
            <td>
                {{DiscountAmount =(Quantity) * (UnitPrice) * (DiscountRate)/100}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{LineTotal =(Quantity) * (UnitPrice) - ((Quantity) * (UnitPrice) * (DiscountRate)/100) }}
            </td>
            <td class="btn-group-xs">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning tip" data-original-title="Quick save" ng-click="addrow()" id="adds">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="item in OrderDetails">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="editMode">
                    {{item.Item_Name}}
                </span>
                <span ng-show="editMode">{{item.Item_Code}}</span>
                <select id='S_{{$index+1}}'  ng-model="ItemSelected"  ng-hide="editMode"   data-ng-change="geteditUnitPrice()" style="width: 100%">

                   <option ng-repeat="i in itemList" value="i.Item_Code">{{i.Item_Name}}</option> 
                </select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="editMode">{{item.Unit_Price}}</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control height24" ng-hide="editMode" ng-model="item.Unit_Price" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="editMode">{{item.Quantity}}</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control height24" ng-hide="editMode" ng-model="item.Quantity" />
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item.Purchase_Cost =(item.Quantity) * (item.Unit_Price)}}

            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="editMode">{{item.Discount_Rate}}</span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control height24" ng-hide="editMode" ng-model="item.Discount_Rate" />
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item.Discount_Amount =(item.Quantity) * (item.Unit_Price) * (item.Discount_Rate)/100}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item.Total_Amount =(item.Quantity) * (item.Unit_Price) - ((item.Quantity) * (item.Unit_Price) * (item.Discount_Rate)/100) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group-xs">
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning tip" data-original-title="Hide" type="button"  ng-show="editMode" ng-click="editMode = false; editItem(item)" id="edit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-original-title="Quick save" type="button"  ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = true" id="update">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>

                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete user" type="button"  value="Delete" ng-click="removeItem($index)" id="remove">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **ng-options** while you are using ng-repeat, here is the brief walkthrough 
https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/

Please have a look and let me know if still there is any confusion.

Comment: i used ng-options then i changed that to ng repeat:

Comment: why you need to change ?

Comment: my orignal code the problem i am facing is i want to set a value to option when in edit mode and when a user chnages item the price will change in price column. My code is working for the row that is not in ng-repeat.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="item in OrderDetails">

                                        <select ng-model="item.Item_Code" ng-hide="editMode"   ng-change="getUnitPricee(item.Item_Code)" style="width: 100%" ng-options="i.Item_Code as i.Item_Name for i in itemList "></select>

Comment: Yes you can do it by using ng-options

Comment: this event is not working/firing in repeated rows ng-change="getUnitPricee(item.Item_Code)"

Comment: It will can you please change your code into ng-options so that we can check it out, maybe there is some other issue you were facing.